# Php5-imagick - Erro na instalação no debian 7

Tags: php, linux, instalador

Não achei nenhuma referência do que poderia ser o erro que exibe quando tento instalar um módulo do php (Php5-imagick)

`root@SMSA443:~# apt-get -f install php5-imagick php5-cgi`

Retorna a mensagem:

```
root@SMSA443:~# apt-get install php5-imagick
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Os seguintes pacotes foram instalados automaticamente e já não são necessários:
  libgd2-xpm liblua5.1-0 php5-cli
Use 'apt-get autoremove' para removê-los.
Os pacotes extra a seguir serão instalados:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-droid ghostscript gsfonts
  imagemagick-common libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap libcups2 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdb5.3 libedit2
  libfontconfig1 libgd3 libgs9 libgs9-common libijs-0.35 libjasper1 libjbig0
  libjbig2dec0 libjson-c2 liblcms2-2 liblqr-1-0 liblua5.1-0 libmagickcore5
  libmagickwand5 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libtiff5 libvpx1 libxml2 lsof php5
  php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-json
  php5-mcrypt php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-sqlite
  php5-sybase php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl poppler-data ttf-dejavu-core
Pacotes sugeridos:
  ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x hpijs cups-common libgd-tools
  libjasper-runtime liblcms2-utils libmagickcore5-extra php-pear
  php5-user-cache poppler-utils fonts-japanese-mincho fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-japanese-gothic fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-arphic-ukai
  fonts-arphic-uming fonts-unfonts-core
Pacotes recomendados:
  php5-readline
Os pacotes a seguir serão REMOVIDOS:
  libapache2-mod-php5
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
  fonts-dejavu-core fonts-droid ghostscript gsfonts imagemagick-common
  libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdb5.3 libgd3 libgs9 libgs9-common
  libijs-0.35 libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjson-c2 liblcms2-2
  liblqr-1-0 liblua5.1-0 libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libpaper-utils
  libpaper1 libtiff5 libvpx1 lsof php5-cgi php5-imagick php5-json poppler-data
Os pacotes a seguir serão atualizados:
  fontconfig-config libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap libcups2 libedit2 libfontconfig1 libxml2 php5 php5-cli
  php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-ming php5-ps
  php5-pspell php5-recode php5-sqlite php5-sybase php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc
  php5-xsl ttf-dejavu-core
26 pacotes atualizados, 30 pacotes novos instalados, 1 a serem removidos e 284 não atualizados.
É preciso baixar 0 B/26,6 MB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 63,1 MB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar [S/n]? S
E: Não foi possível proceder à configuração imediata em 'php5-cgi'. Para detalhes, por favor veja man 5 apt.conf em APT::Immediate-Configure. (2)
root@SMSA443:~#
```

Como informações adicionais, alguns procedimentos e informações que já coletei com a ajuda dos colaboradores.

```
root@XXXXXX:~# ls -la /
drwxrwxrwt 7 root root 4096 Fev 12 09:09 /tmp/ 

root@XXXXXX:~# mount | grep tmp 
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755) 
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755) 
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)

root@XXXXXX:~# aptitude search libc | grep ^i 
i libc6 - Embedded GNU C 

root@XXXXX:~# aptitude search php | grep php5-cgi 
pB php5-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting lang

root@XXXXXX:~# apt-get install libc6 
Lendo listas de pacotes... 
Pronto Construindo Ã¡rvore de dependÃªncias 
Lendo informaÃ§Ã£o de estado... 
Pronto libc6 jÃ¡ Ã© a versÃ£o mais nova. 
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 311 nÃ£o atualizados.
```

Já apaguei os arquivos de instalação do `dpkg` e quando executo retorna o mesmo erro.

Será que alguém já passou por alguma coisa parecida e pode me ajudar?

Comment: Faz bastante tempo que instalei o imagick mas se não me engano ele usa o /tmp pra compilar uma parte dos módulos, então verifique se o seu /tmp está montado com acesso de leitura, escrita e execução.

Comment: `drwxrwxrwt  7 root root  4096 Fev 12 09:09 /tmp/` tá liberado...

Comment: Escreva `mount | grep tmp` e veja se o resultado é este: `tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw)` ou se é este `tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,noexec)` pois se estiver com `noexec` mesmo ele estando com a permissão que você mostrou, ele não irá executar, isso é comum em distros de servidor por questões de segurança.

Comment: `root@SMSA443:~# mount | grep tmp
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
root@SMSA443:~#` Encontrei esse resultado @gabriel-gartz

Comment: Teoricamente sua tmp está montada de forma permissiva, então pode estar faltando alguma lib utilizada na compilação do imagick, tenta instalar libc e ferramentas de compilação: `apt-get install build-essential libc`

Comment: Existem esses `root@SMSA443:~# aptitude search libc | grep ^i
i   libc6                           - Embedded GNU C 
root@SMSA443:~#` o libc6 esta instalado...

Comment: e a `build-essential`? tu precisa ter elas instaladas também, provavelmente se tu der tail no `/var/log/messages` quando for rodar a instalação, ele irá lhe dar mais detalhes do que está quebrando durante o processo de instalação do imagick, vai ficar mais fácil. Por favor verifique, se encontrar mais detalhes edite a pergunta pra poder lhe guiar para resolver esse problema.

Answer (score 1):

**Atualização 12/02/2014**

Experimente baixar o pacote diretamente, no caso aqui:

http://download.unesp.br/linux/debian/pool/main/p/php5/php5-cgi_5.4.4-14+deb7u7_i386.deb

E instale-o diretamente

```
sudo dpkg -i php5-cgi_5.4.4-14+deb7u7_i386.deb
```

(Lembrando que isso é para 32bits, se sua arquitetura for 64bits, adicione um comentário a respeito aqui.)

Depois disso, você pode tentar :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

---

**Antigo**

Algumas vezes esse erro ocorre porque o pacote precisa de uma `libc` mais atualizada para conseguir ser instalado. No entanto essa versão da `libc` ainda não foi instalada. Caso esse seja o problema, você pode tentar:

apt-get update && apt-get install libc6

Se isso funcionar, tente o seguine comando, mas não continue se ele quiser remover algo (principalmente o libc6). Você pode postar nos comentários caso ele tente remover algo.

apt-get install libc6-i686

Se tudo funcionar, rode um apt-get update antes de tentar rodar seus comandos novamente:

apt-get update

Uma coisa importante para adicionar na sua pergunta é se isso só acontece quando você tente instalar o php5-cgi ou acontece com qualquer outro pacote do sistema?

Resposta baseada neste [artigo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244173/how-to-install-apps-when-apt-says-could-not-perform-immediate-configuration) (em inglês)

Comment: `root@SMSA443:~# apt-get install libc6
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo Ã¡rvore de dependÃªncias
Lendo informaÃ§Ã£o de estado... Pronto
libc6 jÃ¡ Ã© a versÃ£o mais nova.
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 311 nÃ£o atualizados.
root@SMSA443:~#` Já está no mais recente, vou tentar a outra opção. Obrigado!

Comment: Executei o `apt-get install libc6-i686` e instalou normal, sem pedir para apagar nada, mas o comando: `apt-get -f install php5-imagick` ainda não funcionou... Obrigado novamente!

Comment: Uma coisa importante para adicionar na sua pergunta é se isso só acontece quando você tente instalar o php5-cgi ou acontece com qualquer outro pacote do sistema?

Comment: Somente com o pacote: php5-imagick

Comment: Já instalei o php5-gd; php5-sqlite; php5-sybase e etc...

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado a todos que contribuirão.

O problema era que precisava desinstalar o php5-cgi, depois instalar o "Image Magick" e seu modulo ao php, mas para isso ele pede para desinstalar um tanto de modulo, entre eles o libapache2-mod-php5 que pode fazer suas paginas pararem de funcionar, mas basta reinstala-los.

Ainda estou com alguns erros devido essa instalação, que por sinal não recomento. No mais, é isso!

Obrigado novamente.